# O que pode fazer com o Firebase do Google?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Eu conheci o Firebase há algum tempo, mas nunca consegui fazer nada, eu gostaria de saber o que eu posso usar, fazer, criar etc utilizando as APIs, etc.

Obs: Nada de aplicativo Mobile, somente Web!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação fornecida pelo próprio google https://firebase.google.com/features/ o firebase possui diversas funcionalidades, como:

- Mensageiro na nuvem
- serviço de autenticação
- banco de dados em realtime
- armazenamento de arquivos
- hosting arquivos web
- notificações
- suporte facilitado para monetização por ads

Firebase é uma plataforma muito grande. Caso queira aprender e testar a sua primeira aplicação te recomendo esse vídeo que mostra o como é fácil criar a sua primeira aplicação usando a funcionalidade de exemplo banco de dados realtime, `spoiler` é impressionante.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1D0_wFlXgo

Caso queira aprender ainda mais sobre o firebase na web segue link da playlist completa fornecida pela equipe do firebase.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX

Comment: obrigado amigo, porém a maior parte desses recursos são apenas para aplicativos mobile! Eu sou apenas focado na parte da Web!